DocumentExtractionSkill doesn't extract text from blob data
I have a DB
TABLE FileStorage (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FileName NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,     -- Name of the file
    FileData VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL,    -- Binary data of the file PDF
    UploadDate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE() -- Optional: Date of file upload
);

In cognitive search:
Index:
{
  "name": "files-index",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "ID",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "key": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": true,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "fileName",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": true,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "content",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": true,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": true,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "uploadDate",
      "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset",
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": true,
      "synonymMaps": []
    }
  ],
  "scoringProfiles": [],
  "suggesters": [],
  "analyzers": [],
  "tokenizers": [],
  "tokenFilters": [],
  "charFilters": [],
  "normalizers": [],
  "similarity": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.BM25Similarity"
  },
  "@odata.etag": ""
}

skill
{
  "name": "testtwo",
  "description": "testtwo",
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Util.DocumentExtractionSkill",
      "name": "#1",
      "description": "Extract text and metadata from binary documents (PDF, DOCX, etc.)",
      "context": "/document",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "file_data",
          "source": "/document/file_data",
          "inputs": []
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "targetName": "content"
        },
        {
          "name": "metadata",
          "targetName": "metadata"
        }
      ],
      "parsingMode": "default",
      "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
      "_configuration": {}
    }
  ],
  "@odata.etag": ""
}

indexer:
{
    "name": "filestorage-indexer",
    "dataSourceName": "filestorage-datasource",
    "targetIndexName": "files-index",
    "skillsetName": "testtwo",
    "fieldMappings": [
        {
            "sourceFieldName": "ID",
            "targetFieldName": "id"
        },
        {
            "sourceFieldName": "FileName",
            "targetFieldName": "fileName"
        }
    ],
    "outputFieldMappings": [
        {
            "sourceFieldName": "/document/content",
            "targetFieldName": "content"
        },
        {
            "sourceFieldName": "/document/metadata",
            "targetFieldName": "metadata"
        }
    ]
}

but the result is empty in content:
{
  "@odata.context": "https://someurl.windows.net/indexes('files-index')/$metadata#docs(*)",
  "@odata.count": 29,
  "value": [
    {
      "@search.score": 1,
      "ID": "20",
      "fileName": "firstfile.pdf",
      "content": null,
      "metadata": null,
      "uploadDate": null
    },{
      "@search.score": 1,
      "ID": "3",
      "fileName": "blabla.pdf",
      "content": null,
      "metadata": null,
      "uploadDate": null
    },

I’m currently working on a project where I need to extract the content of multiple files and place it into a content field. However, I’ve hit a roadblock and I’m not sure how to proceed. I’ve tried various methods, but I seem to be stuck at this point. The issue is that I can’t seem to get the content from the files into the field as expected.
At this stage, I’m unsure whether the issue is with my technical skills or if my overall approach is flawed. I’ve reviewed the code several times and have double-checked my logic, but the desired result is still not being achieved.
It could be that there’s a step I’m missing, or perhaps a more efficient way of handling the file content that I haven’t considered yet. I’m open to suggestions on how to proceed or alternative ways to solve the problem.

Check that the Document Extraction Skill is correctly referencing the file_data field in your data source.

The DocumentExtractionSkill supports formats like PDF, DOCX, etc. If unsupported formats are present in the FileData, they will fail.


I’ve reviewed the code several times and have double-checked my logic, but the desired result is still not being achieved.

The above JSON skillset is having an issue with the inputs for the file_data field. Specifically, the inputs array within the source property is not required and could be causing a problem.

The skillset should directly match to the FileData field for binary content extraction and remove unnecessary properties like inputs: [] inside the source.

{
  "name": "testtwo",
  "description": "testtwo",
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Util.DocumentExtractionSkill",
      "name": "#1",
      "description": "Extract text and metadata from binary documents (PDF, DOCX, etc.)",
      "context": "/document",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "file_data",
          "source": "/document/FileData"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "targetName": "content"
        },
        {
          "name": "metadata",
          "targetName": "metadata"
        }
      ],
      "parsingMode": "default",
      "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata"
    }
  ]
}

The indexer must map the database fields correctly to the index fields and check output mappings from the skillset are properly assigned.
Sample data:

Limit the indexer to process a single document. This helps identify issues with specific records.

In the indexer configuration, add a filter to include one ID (e.g., WHERE ID = 1).

{
  "name": "filestorage-indexer",
  "dataSourceName": "filestorage-datasource",
  "targetIndexName": "files-index",
  "skillsetName": "testtwo",
  "fieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "ID",
      "targetFieldName": "ID"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "FileName",
      "targetFieldName": "fileName"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "UploadDate",
      "targetFieldName": "uploadDate"
    }
  ],
  "outputFieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/content",
      "targetFieldName": "content"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/metadata",
      "targetFieldName": "metadata"
    }
  ],
  "parameters": {
    "batchSize": 100,
    "maxFailedItems": 0,
    "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": 0
  }
}

The output fields (content, metadata) align with the target index fields correctly.

